# Laravel migration (errno: 150 “Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed”)

Tags: php, html, laravel-5

I am trying to get specific data from the database by using columns `chatter_discussion` when a user clicks a link but I am getting this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table
>   `forums.chatter_discussion` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is
>   incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `chatter_discussion` add
>   constraint `chatter_discussion_user_id_foreign` foreign key
>   (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`) on delete cascade on update
>   cascade)

```
Schema::table('chatter_discussion', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('chatter_category_id')->references('id')->on('chatter_categories')
        ->onDelete('cascade')
        ->onUpdate('cascade');
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
        ->onDelete('cascade')
        ->onUpdate('cascade');
});

Schema::table('chatter_post', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('chatter_discussion_id')->references('id')->on('chatter_discussion')
        ->onDelete('cascade')
        ->onUpdate('cascade');
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
        ->onDelete('cascade')
        ->onUpdate('cascade');
    });
}
```

Comment: You can help others to help you by posting the definition of the users table.

Answer (score 1):

The problem generally happens when migrating to new versions of Laravel which use `bigIncrements` instead of `increments` when defining primary keys in schema. 
Also you need to define the type of the foreign key before defining the foreign key relationship.

The fix is to define the type of the foreign key and THEN define the foreign key relation, for example:

```
Schema::table('chatter_discussion', function (Blueprint $table) {
// first define the type of the foreign keys in the schema
$table->bigInteger('chatter_category_id')->unsigned(); // the id of the chatter category
$table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned(); // the id of the user
/*
or use:
$table->integer('chatter_category_id');
$table->integer('user_id');
if using older versions of laravel, whatever works
*/        
// THEN define foreign key relations
$table->foreign('chatter_category_id')->references('id')->on('chatter_categories')
                    ->onDelete('cascade')
                    ->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
                    ->onDelete('cascade')
                    ->onUpdate('cascade');
    });
```

Do similar for other tables which reference foreign keys

**NOTE** in your example you dont define an `id` column in `chatter_discussion` table which is then referenced in `chatter_post`. Not sure if you missed it or it is defined in a previous migration.

Comment: thank you but i have  chatter_category_id and user_id  already defined in two table they was migrated successfully

Comment: @AbdessatarGhoudi, if you already have defined the foreign key columns, then possibly the datatypes of the columns do not match (eg use bigIncrements instead of incerements or vice-versa). Most often this is the problem. You can edit your question and add these migrations so I can know what goes wrong and reply accordingly

Answer (score 0):

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->text('address');
        $table->string('tel1');
        $table->string('tel2');
        $table->integer('owner');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('access_id');
        $table->string('depot_number')->default(2);
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('access_id')->references('id')->on('accesses')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('accesses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('type');
        $table->string('description');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

In your **database/migrations** folder, sort by name. Then make sure **create_accesses_table** is before **create_companies_table**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xR7hl.png)